# Collision of objects

Tags: libgdx

I am just new in libgdx and I've been looking for a better solution to my problem. The stick man must catch the ball when he's going through it but I really don't know how to detect each time the stick man passes through the ball.

P.S. the ball can be dragged and drop by the user in order to avoid the stick man.

Comment: We have no chance at knowing how you are building this. You have to post som code so we can see what you are working with.

Comment: I don't know what code I must post because I only need to know on how to detect if the stick man is going to catch the ball. My game is like "Save the Cursor" from the facebook game.

Comment: show the code for the ball and the stickman. I don't know what "Save the Cursor" is. And it does not show me what YOU are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code and with the very vague description you are giving, I will attempt and answer.

On you ball and on you stickman you make a Rectangle with the size of the ball and stickman and their coordinates.

```
Rectangle bound = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
```

When moving the objects around you move the rectangles too.

Then you check if they overlap:

```
if(stickman.bound.overlaps(ball.bound)){
    //collision
}
```